# upgrade:all in typo3_console for TYPO3 9.5 does not work correctly

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-console

TYPO3 9.5.3
typo3_console 5.6 from TER (last version)

I try to run all updates via typo3_console:

```
./typo3cms upgrade:all --arguments=typo3DbLegacyExtension[install]=1,adminpanelExtension[install]=1,funcExtension[install]=0
```

the upgrades are running but i get this question:

```
[Optional] Install extensions "dbal" and "adodb" from TER.
Install (y/N) N
12/12 [============================] 100%
```

I typed N but dbal and adodb are installed anyway, and the func Extension too. After finishing the installation crashes until i manually remove and deaktivate all three of them.

Any ideas why typo3_console is behaving so weired? yy

Comment: The upgrade wizard to download and install are not available in TYPO3 9.5, so my question would be where this wizard comes from at all in your case. It has even been disabled for 8.7: https://review.typo3.org/#/c/54070/ So there seems to be something weird within your setup.

Comment: But there is indeed a bug in TYPO3 Console, which makes it impossible to skip such wizards: https://github.com/TYPO3-Console/TYPO3-Console/issues/795

Comment: @helhum: The upgrade wizard for dbal and adodb is part of typo3db_legacy. But i need this extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i found some explanation: the upgrade wizard for dbal and adodb is part of typo3db_legacy which implements the old database classes. If you need these classes you are struck with both upgrade wizards :-) In combination with the bug in TYPO3 Console which makes it impossible to skip these wizards this problem is not exactly solvable but i found a little workaround: just after running all upgrade wizards i advice TYPO3 console to deinstall both extensions and delete the cache. This keeps the installation running and the further actions will work as expected.